# yii rest api controller fails

Tags: php, rest, yii

Am new to the rest api in the yii2 framework.
I have a controller where am sending a post request via postman but it doesnt work

I HAVE TRIED
1.API Controller

```
<?php

   namespace restapi\controllers;
use yii\rest\Controller;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
//use app\models\Post;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use frontend\models\SignupForm;
use frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm;

 class ApiController extends Controller
 {

public function actionResetpassword(){
    $model = new PasswordResetRequestForm();

    if(\Yii::$app->request->post() && $model->validate()){
       return 2;
    }

    else{
        return 1;            

    }
  //return $response;

}
```

}

The model

```
<?php
 namespace frontend\models;

 use common\models\User;
 use yii\base\Model;
  use Yii;

class PasswordResetRequestForm extends Model
 {
public $email;


  public function rules()
    {
    return [
       // ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['email', 'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
         ['email', 'exist',
            'targetClass' => '\common\models\User',
            'filter' => ['status' => User::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            'message' => 'There is no user with such email.'
        ],
    ];
  }
 }
```

Whenever i make a post request via post man with form data i the body i still get 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not loading the POST data into your model

use this :

```
if($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
    return 2;
}else{
    return 1;
}
```